# Follow up on previous question concerning the [money] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, burninate-request

Following up on, [Why do we have both a [money] and a [currency] tag?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4754/26455), there are currently 2 <strike>14</strike> questions remaining that use the [money](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) tag. After these questions have been edited the [money] tag may be made a synonym of [currency].

- <strike>[Are/were there any countries where rich people have more votes?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/are-were-there-any-countries-where-rich-people-have-more-votes)</strike>
- [Hypothetical situations: private money or absolute monopoly upon money supply](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/hypothetical-situations-private-money-or-absolute-monopoly-upon-money-supply)
- [How might a business overthrow the U.S. government? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10116/how-might-a-business-overthrow-the-u-s-government)
- [What sort of evidence exists that higher salaries for political offices attract better candidates?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/what-sort-of-evidence-exists-that-higher-salaries-for-political-offices-attract)
- [All time highest net worth of a Presidential cabinet in constant dollars?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14017/all-time-highest-net-worth-of-a-presidential-cabinet-in-constant-dollars)
- [Has high taxation of the rich been sustainable as an economic policy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19757/has-high-taxation-of-the-rich-been-sustainable-as-an-economic-policy)
- [If the US decided to inflate its way out of their debt, what would the value of the dollar drop to? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20148/if-the-us-decided-to-inflate-its-way-out-of-their-debt-what-would-the-value-of)
- [Did US make any significant fiscal changes following Panama Papers disclosures?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/did-us-make-any-significant-fiscal-changes-following-panama-papers-disclosures)
- [What political aspects prevent land purchases in North America moving national borders? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21824/what-political-aspects-prevent-land-purchases-in-north-america-moving-national-b)
- [What is currently stopping the most developed states from completely abandoning cash?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21941/what-is-currently-stopping-the-most-developed-states-from-completely-abandoning)
- [Why do tourists have to declare $10,000 or more entering some countries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25913/why-do-tourists-have-to-declare-10-000-or-more-entering-some-countries)
- [How can the influence of wealthy individuals on democratic processes be reduced?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25993/how-can-the-influence-of-wealthy-individuals-on-democratic-processes-be-reduced)
- [Is UK entitled for the brexit divorce payment refund if it rejoins later?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26283/is-uk-entitled-for-the-brexit-divorce-payment-refund-if-it-rejoins-later)
- [Why are payment processors politically inserting themselves into Internet police-dom? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37441/why-are-payment-processors-politically-inserting-themselves-into-internet-police)

Comment: So what's the consensus on these tags now? I assume your answer on the linked question is now outdated. As I understand it, the [money] tag is too broad and we have more specific tags that are useful: e.g the [debt], [budget], [money-supply] and [campaign-finance] tags. Maybe an answer should be posted here to propose what should and shouldn't be in-scope for the [currency] tag?

Comment: "Follow up on previous question concerning the [money] tag" could be shortened to [Follow the money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follow_the_money).

Comment: This part is finished and I created the tag synonym that remaps [money] to [currency]. The last question was a bit of an odd one, rather than having a tag for payment service providers, I think that fits within the scope of the [banking] tag. I created a synonym for that as well and edited the [banking] tag guidance to reflect the broader scope. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @JJJ - It all looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consensus, to the best of my knowledge and belief, has not changed with regard to the [currency] tag — it should be retained. The discussion for the [money] tag took place in comments.

On April 11, 2021, I changed the [currency] [tag excerpt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/currency/info) to read,

> Questions about a system of money in general use in a particular country or its relationship to international trade, such as, exchange rates or reserve currencies.

(Though crypto- and digital currencies may deserve mention.)

And changed the [money] [tag excerpt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/money/info) to read,

> Questions related to the political aspect of money. If the question names a currency, consider [currency] as an alternative. If a tag implies money, the [money] tag is unnecessary or redundant.

But, in fact, the [money] tag is "too broad" because it is a meta-tag and for that reason should not be used, nor removed (someone might use it anew); thus the recommendation that it be made a synonym of [currency].

In [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/tagging),

> **Avoid meta-tags**
>
> Do not use meta-tags in questions. Here are some tips to help you determine whether a tag is a meta-tag:
>
> - **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are not helpful by themselves – they do not communicate anything about the content of the question.

The [money] tag doesn't work well "as the only tag on the question," because the question is, in some way, about how the money is used, rather than about money itself.

**Note:** Of the original 64 questions tagged [money], 50 have already been re-tagged. I posted the "question" more as a reminder and notification that additional re-tagging needs to be completed.

Comment: I agree that [money] isn't a good tag because it's too broad. I don't think it's a meta tag though, as it does describe that the question is about money (which distinguishes the question from many others on our site). Nevertheless, I agree with your proposed process (remove the money tag where needed and then merge it into [currency]). and where needed a new specific tag can be introduced (similar to the tags I mentioned in my comment under the question).

Comment: @JJJ, Rick Smith but money is not currency.  Rick recently retagged a question about the M2 money supply, which includes cash [along with bank deposits, money market securities, mutual funds, and other time deposits](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/m2.asp).  Another question was about reporting requirements on crossing borders.  These typically concern cash _and cash equivalents,_ or as the US calls them, [monetary instruments](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-195), which include traveler's checks, blank checks, and checks or securities payable to the bearer.

Comment: @phoog so do you disagree with the proposal? I think the idea now is that money isn't a good fit as a tag and one way of avoiding the tag being used is to make it a synonym of another tag. Of course currency isn't a good fit for all money-related questions, but the synonym prevents the new tag from being created. If you suggest a different approach, feel free to do so explicitly (either discussing it in comments or proposing it as an answer directly). Maybe we need a good meta post about tag guidance for all money-related tags?

Comment: @JJJ well I suppose I'm convinced by the argument that most wouldn't know how to use them correctly.  The first question I mentioned also has the [tag:money-supply] tag, so maybe the solution is just to delete the [tag:currency] (formerly [tag:money]) tag from it altogether.

Comment: @phoog - I considered the question at length before re-tagging. The question is about the US dollar, which is a currency. However, in some other cases related to [money-supply], I removed the [money] tag. I had considered removing it in this case, but chose to retain the [currency] tag. I have no objection to removing the [currency] tag from that question.

Comment: @phoog yea, on that question I don't think either of the tags are needed, [money-supply] accurately covers the question (and [currency] falls short because as you say not all monetary instruments are currency). If you have a good understanding of the different money-related terms then feel free to start a meta Q&A about tag usage. With the [economy] and [finance] tags I think there's some overlap as well. Though maybe that's a separate issue?

Comment: @RickSmith yea I hadn't thought of it like that. But by that logic, aren't all money-supply questions about currency? I mean, even most non-cash monetary instruments (except mutual funds?) are expressed in some currency, I think.

Comment: @JJJ - That question was about using inflation to, in effect, change the value of the currency over time. That would not be true, necessarily, of other questions about money supply.

Comment: Fair enough.  Let's keep the currency tag.

Comment: Yea that makes sense, then it's correctly tagged (and having it there doesn't really hurt anyway). Phoog is right about the difficulty with these tags though. For most of our users I don't think it's super clear which tag to use when. Even on Money.SE and Economics.SE I don't think there's tag guidance on [money-supply].